# Getting some extra exceptions and messages on screen when my triggers gets fired

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

This is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER unsuccessful_logins
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
    ON temp_logins
    for each row

DECLARE

        CURSOR c_unsuccessful_attempts 
        IS
        SELECT * from temp_attempts
         and user_id= :new.user_id;

    max_fails EXCEPTION;


    BEGIN
         FOR r_unsuccessful_attempts in c_unsuccessful_attempts  
         LOOP

             if(:new.user_id = r_unsuccessful_attempts.user_id) then
                 if (r_unsuccessful_attempts.locked = 'Y') then
                    raise max_fails;
                end if;
            else
                null;
            end if;

        END LOOP;       

EXCEPTION  
    WHEN max_fails THEN  
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20300,'User '''||:new.login_name||''' has reached maximum failed logins. Please contact your system administrator ');    

   END unsuccessful_logins;
```

The error I am getting in my oracle apps screen is:

```
APP-01564: ORACLE error 20300 in fdssgn
cause: fdssgn failed due to ORA-20300: You have reached maximum failed logins. Please contact your system administrator.
    ORA-06512: at "APPS.UNSUCCESSFUL_LOGINS",line 24
    ORA-04088: error during excution of trigger 'APPS.UNSUCCESSFUL_LOGINS'.
```

The SQL statement being executed at the time of the error was: 
    INSERT INTO TEMP_LOGINS (USER_ID, ATTEMPT_TIME,TERMINAL_ID,LOGIN_NAME)
    values(:user_id, sysdate,:erminal_id,:login_name)

I just want to display `ORA-20300: You have reached maximum failed logins. Please contact your system administrator` part.

And want to omit:

```
    ORA-06512: at "APPS.UNSUCCESSFUL_LOGINS",line 24
    ORA-04088: error during excution of trigger 'APPS.UNSUCCESSFUL_LOGINS'.
  The SQL statement being executed at the time of the error was: 
INSERT INTO TEMP_LOGINS (USER_ID, ATTEMPT_TIME,TERMINAL_ID,LOGIN_NAME)
values(:user_id, sysdate,:erminal_id,:login_name)
```

How can I get rid off these extra messages on the screen?

Comment: What are the messages and errors you see? What are the table definitions? (And why are you using a cursor at all; and not even passing the user ID as a parameter to it?)

Comment: What extra exceptions and message are you getting?  Also, why are you pulling all records from the temp_attempts table and looping over them when you could query for the locked records you are interested in directly?

Comment: +1 to Alex for saying exactly what I was thinking before I posted.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments. Sorry, I'm not very old to oracle. I'll correct the cursor.

Comment: I've edited my question above, with all the messages I'm getting. Please help!

Comment: At a guess (and thus not worthy of being an answer), it looks like you need to catch the exception in your application and handle it locally, maybe displaying your own alert or whatever with the text of the exception. This isn't one I'm familiar with, but it looks like the app is letting it bubble up until it has to handle it in a default way, which adds the extra messages from its own handler?

Comment: @prashant1988 - what is your application built in? Are you running the insert from APEX, Oracle Forms, an SQL*Plus script...? It would probably be helpful to see more of the code around the insert statement.

Comment: Actually it is oracle apps. When an user will have a unsuccessful login, a record will get inserted into temp_logins tables in the back end. When these unsuccessful logins reaches 3, a record will get inserted into temp_attempts tables with TEMP_ATTEMPTS.LOCKED set to 'Y'. All, this happens in the back end. Now, when the user tries to login for the 4th time, he/she should get a popup message on the screen as I have mentioned in the exception block.    Hope the problem is clear. Please let me know if there is any solution to remove these extra lines from the popup message. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by 'oracle apps', but [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18727_01/doc.121/e12897/T302934T307517.htm) may help; it has a section on exception handling.

As I suggested in an earlier comment, I suspect you need something in your application code to catch and gracefully handle the exception raised by the trigger, so some kind of wrapper around the insert statement. The link is specifically talking about handling an exception in Forms, which (as is probably quite clear) I'm not familiar with, but the principal is likely to be the same if you're using something related.

Adapting their example slightly, something like this *might* fit what I *think* you're trying to do:

```
DECLARE
    too_many_attempts EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(too_many_attempts, -20300);
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TEMP_LOGINS (USER_ID, ATTEMPT_TIME,TERMINAL_ID,LOGIN_NAME)
    values(:user_id, sysdate,:erminal_id,:login_name);
EXCEPTION
    WHEN too_many_attempts THEN
       fnd_message.set_string(SQLERRM);
       fnd_message.error;
       RAISE FORM_TRIGGER_FAILURE;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex. That link is quite useful. Yes, You are right, its oracle application forms. I'll try this out now.

Comment: Many thanks for the link. I read the whole article and found the solution finally. Actually there is no need to touch my application code. I've mentioned the below in my trigger code:    FND_MESSAGE.SET_NAME ('FND', 'FLEX-USER DEFINED ERROR');                                         FND_MESSAGE.SET_TOKEN ('MSG', 'You have reached maximum failed logins. This account has been locked temporarily. Please contact your administrator');
APP_EXCEPTION.RAISE_EXCEPTION; where 'FLEX-USER DEFINED ERROR' is the message code I have to setup for my application. It is working for me. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @prashant1998 - glad to help. Feel free to upvote/accept if the link was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is, you can not omit output from RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR. You could consider using dbms_output.put_line to provide a single message.

...

```
WHEN max_fails THEN 
  dbms_output.put_line('User Message');
```

Comment: Thanks! I was also thinking about the same. But the question is : Will it be able TO give a popup message on my oracle apps screen?

Comment: I've tried using dbms_output.put_line. It is raising the exception in backend but no popups.. no errors on the screen. Please help!